# How to update Bundle in Apache Felix OSGi Framework

Tags: osgi, bundle, apache-felix, pax-runner

I'm having troubles updating my bundle from the `gogo shell`.
I have a `gogo shell` running on terminal. My bundles are active in there.

Now when I make changes to the code, what steps are necessary to forward these changes into the running OSGi framework?

I ran update `<bundleId>` but nothing happens. It still runs the same version which was compiled when I started the framework.
Before the update command I opened another terminal and ran `mvn clean install` (I'm using `maven-bundle-plugin` along with `pax-construct`).

Comment: Is the OSGi Framework running on your computer or do you have a remote connection with your terminal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When working with Maven, my workflow for checking updated code involves two terminals.

- After updating the code, I run `mvn install` from the project which will build the actual bundle. Keep track of the absolute location on your system where the target bundle is built.
- In the running framework, I update the bundle, giving it a URL; something like `update 25 file:///Users/you/project/bundle/target/bundle.jar`

If you're free not to use Maven and Pax Runner, you can also take a look at [bndtools](https://github.com/njbartlett/bndtools), which is an Eclipse plugin. You can then still take the bundles that bndtools builds for you, and run them with Pax Runner.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The absolute classpath did it. I tried with relative before but got an I/O exception. (or maybe I mispelled it..)

Answer (score 0):

Another try is via OBR local repo as follows:

 - assume artifact is called test-api, then

a)`g! deploy test-api` deployed under id: 25

 after further changes made to the code and `mvn clean install` do:

1)`g! update 25`
2)`g! refresh`
if no result then before step 1) try `g! repos refresh file:///c:/Users/.m2/repository.xml` to refresh local OBR repo